# Replace remote file using terminal (im already connected)

Tags: mac, terminal

I am connected to a remote mac via terminal (did ssh *machinename*). I am looking at a file that I want to replace with a file from my local machine. Something like:

```
$ ls
   foo/  grok/  target.txt
```

so I want to replace "target.txt" with a target.txt that lives on my own machine. How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use scp to copy it over.  You could edit the file on the remote system and copy and paste from your local copy.

Comment: Ah ok, I just realized, I could use vi to edit the file in-place (that'll be much easier). The file seems to be in read-only mode, can I put it in write-mode temporarily to edit it?

Comment: Assuming that you own the file, chmod u+w target.txt to edit and then chmod u-w target.txt to set it read-only.

Comment: Yeah right now the file has the following permission: "-rw-r--r--" but when I try "chmod u+w target.txt", I get no error, but the permission remains the same.

Comment: If you are the owner of the file, you should have write access to it already.

Comment: Oh whoops I had + instead of -. Yeah now I get an error "Operation not permitted".

Comment: Seems to imply that file is not owned by you.  If you have sudo privs try, sudo vi target.txt